# UICollectionView header title disappears after

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I build a collection view based on a dataset. When I perform a clean install all header titles show up correct. After reopening the app, the first header title disappears. And calling reloadData in the viewWillAppear method is not fixing the problem.

My code:

```
    #import "ChapterViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "ChapterStore.h"
#import "Chapter.h"
#import "Section.h"
#import "Word.h"
#import "ChapterViewCell.h"

@interface ChapterViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;

@end

@implementation ChapterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Chapters"];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ( ![userDefaults valueForKey:@"version"] )
        {
            [[ChapterStore sharedStore] doParse];

            [self spaceTrimmer:[ChapterStore sharedStore]];


            // Adding version number to NSUserDefaults for first version:
            [userDefaults setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"version"];
        }


        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"version"] == [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] )
        {
            /// Same Version so dont run the function
        }
        else
        {
            // Call Your Function;

            // Update version number to NSUserDefaults for other versions:
            [userDefaults setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"version"];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[self collectionView] reloadData];    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfChapters {
    return [[[ChapterStore sharedStore] allChapters] count];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *chapters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self numberOfChapters]; i++) {
        [chapters addObject:[[[ChapterStore sharedStore] allChapters] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    self.dataArray = chapters;

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChapterViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChapterViewHeader" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"cvHeader"];


    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(159, 159)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:2];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:2];
    [flowLayout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(0, 50)];


    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

}


- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"cvHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Chapter *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *chapterName = [data CHAPTER_NAME];

    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[header viewWithTag:99];

    [titleLabel setText:chapterName];

    return header;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Chapter *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    Section *section = [[data sections]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellData = [section SECTION_NAME];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    ChapterViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    int i = [indexPath indexAtPosition:0] + 1;
    int j = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1] + 1;

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%ds%d.jpg", i,j];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [cell setController:self];
    [cell setCollectionView:collectionView];

    [[cell sectionLabel] setText:cellData];

    [[cell imageView]setImage:image];

    return cell;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Chapter *sectionArray = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[sectionArray sections] count];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a caching or an IOS 7 upgrade issue. I completely uninstalled the app, restarted xcode and the simulator and the issue is now gone.